# Probability of rolling any number 10 times at any given point in the sequence

Tags: probability, combinatorics, games

Imagine a race, where each runner has a number, the race track is 100 meters, and each time you roll a fair 6-sided die, the corresponding runner moves 10 meters. I would like to calculate the probability of any given runner winning, at any point in the sequence.

So for example, the first roll a 3. Now #3 needs 9 more rolls to reach 10 total (to win) and all other numbers need 10 more.

Lets say the next five rolls are 1, 4, 3, 3, and 6.

Now #3 needs 7 rolls; #1, #4, and #6 need 9 rolls; and #2 and #5 needs 10 rolls still.

So, at this point in time, what is the probability that #3 is rolled 7 times before any other number is rolled its corresponding amount to reach 10 total rolls.

Comment: This is a slight generalization of the problem of the [Unfinished Game](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_points) (a question appearing in late Medieval manuscripts dating to the 1200's) whose analysis, c. 1650, touched off the formal study of probability theory.  Consider, then, beginning by solving your problem with 6 runners replaced by 2 (which is the original version).

Comment: This seems to be similar to [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511705/probability-of-winning), for which the exact solution involves summing over the multinomial PMF across multiple counts of rolls. It might be a good exercise to simulate this, but I'm not sure if you're looking for something more analytical.